# How to pass class parameter to saveAsSequenceFile() in scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to call this method in my scala program

```
  SequenceFileRDDFunctions.saveAsSequenceFile(path: String, codec: Option[Class[_ <: CompressionCodec]] = None)
```

I am going to give "BZip2Codec" as the second parameter. However, I tried below but it failed to compile:

```
 import org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec
 ....
 rdd.saveAsSequenceFile(path, Option[BZip2Codec]) 
 // missing arguments for method apply in object Option; 
 // follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
```

Can someone please help how to pass class "BZip2Codec" as the second parameter ?  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rdd.saveAsSequenceFile(path, Some(classOf[BZip2Codec]))
```