# Compressing ObjectFiles in spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

It is a fairly simple question actually, with saveAsTextFile we have the possibility to specify compression:

```
def saveAsTextFile(path: String, codec: Class[_ <: CompressionCodec]): Unit
```

But i find that lacking on saveAsObjectFile. Short of moving all uses of this to dataframes, what are my options to compress the file?

I have tried setting these

```
spark.conf.set("spark.checkpoint.compress", "true")
spark.conf.set("spark.rdd.compress", "true")

spark.conf.set("spark.io.compression.codec", "snappy")
```

with no luck.

Thanks

Comment: You can try saveAsSequenceFile - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35853973/how-to-pass-class-parameter-to-saveassequencefile-in-scala)

Comment: Thanks, this would be my last choice indeed, but i am trying to keep sveAsObjectFile. I have edited my question to reflect that setting the parameters did not work.